# Pasiva de proceso y pasiva de estado en diferentes tiempos

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto, voz-pasiva, pretérito-perfecto

Quiero entender en una manera sistemática diferencias entre la pasiva de proceso y la pasiva de estado. He hecho una lista con todos los tiempos, y con ser y estar, y he escrito lo que entiendo. ¿Podéis decirme si mis explicaciones son correctos, y responder a las preguntas?

**Presente**

1. **La policía recoge los testimonios.** (acción no terminada)
2. **Los testimonios son recogidos.** (acción no terminada, el mismo significado que 1, pero deenfatiza el agente)
3. **Los testimonios están recogidos.** (acción terminada, énfasis sólo en el resultado)

**Pretérito imperfecto**

4. **La policía recogía los testimonios.** (acción no terminada en un punto del pasado)
5. **Los testimonios eran recogidos.** (acción no terminada en un punto del pasado, el mismo significado que 4, deenfatiza el agente)
6. **Los testimonios estaban recogidos.** (acción terminada en un punto del pasado, énfasis sólo en el resultado)

**Pretérito indefinido**

7. **La policía recogió los testimonios.** (acción terminada, ¿énfasis tanto en la acción como en el resultado?)
8. **Los testimonios fueron recogidos.** (acción terminada, el mismo significado que 7, deenfatiza el agente)
9. **Los testimonios estuvieron recogidos.** (¿es correcto o no? ¿es diferente que 8?)

**Pretérito perfecto**

10. **La policía ha recogido los testimonios.** (¿acción terminada o no?)
11. **Los testimonios han sido recogidos.** (¿el mismo significado que 10? ¿también el mismo significado que 3? ¿3 enfatiza sólo el resultado, pero 11 enfatiza tanto la acción como el resultado?)
12. **Los testimonios han estado recogidos.** (¿es correcto o no? ¿qué significa?)

**Pretérito pluscuamperfecto**

13. **La policía había recogido los testimonios.** (acción terminada en un punto del pasado)
14. **Los testimonios habían sido recogidos.** (¿el mismo significado que 13? ¿el mismo significado que 6 pero enfatiza tanto la acción como el resultado?)
15. **Los testimonios habían estado recogidos.** (¿es correcto o no? ¿qué significa?)

**Futuro simple**

16. **La policía recogerá los testimonios.** (acción no terminada en un punto del futuro)
17. **Los testimonios serán recogidos.** (acción no terminada en un punto del futuro, deenfatiza el agente)
18. **Los testimonios estarán recogidos.** (acción terminada en un punto del futuro, énfasis en el resultado)

**Futuro perfecto**

19. **La policía habrá recogido los testimonios.** (acción terminada en un punto del futuro)
20. **Los testimonios habrán sido recogidos.** (acción terminada en un punto del futuro, ¿el mismo significado que 19 y 18? ¿énfasis tanto en el resultado como en la acción?)
21. **Los testimonios habrán estado recogidos.** (¿es correcto o no?)

**Condicional simple**

22. **La policía recogería los testimonios.** (acción hipotética no terminada)
23. **Los testimonios serían recogidos.** (acción hipotética no terminada, el mismo significado que 22, deenfatiza el agente)
24. **Los testimonios estarían recogidos.** (acción hipotética terminada)

**Condicional perfecto**

25. **La policía habría recogido los testimonios.** (¿acción terminada?)
26. **Los testimonios habrían sido recogidos.** (¿el mismo significado que 25 y 24?)
27. **Los testimonios habrían estado recogidos.** (¿es correcto o no?)

Comment: Hola michau, actualmente la pregunta contiene muchísimas cosas a contestar. ¿No sería mejor desglosarla en preguntas más pequeñas para así dar respuestas más detalladas y completas?

Comment: @fedorqui Hola, no estoy seguro como desglosarla bien. Hacer una pregunta para cada tiempo no me parece adecuado, ¿eh? De todas formas, no hay problema si las repuestas sólo contestan a algunas de mis preguntas.

Comment: Podrías agrupar los condicionales, los futuros, los pretéritos... De todos modos, creo que sigue siendo una pregunta demasiado amplia. No puedes suponer que alguien irá punto a punto revisando 27 cosas diferentes. Haz preguntas concretas, tal y como se sugiere en [ask].